# Using conditions when replacing data in Notepad++

Tags: regex, string, conditional-statements, notepad++, line

In my document in Notepad++, I have lines like these:

```
dicha   NCFS000 dicha-n dicha   NCFS000 dicha   F   S
medida  NCFS000 medida-n    medida  NCFS000 medida  F   S
```

And I want to replace the line `dicha   NCFS000 dicha-n dicha   NCFS000 dicha   F   S` with `dicha  VMP00SF decir-v dicha   VMP00SF decir   F   S` when next line includes the first string `NCFS000`. It must be preceded by a string (in this case `medida`), but it can be any string.

A query to find this lines is like this:

```
dicha   NCFS000 dicha-n dicha   NCFS000 dicha   F   S\r\n(\w*)  NCFS000
```

This query match the condition because:

1. the first line is `dicha NCFS000 dicha-n dicha   NCFS000 dicha   F   S`
2. Then, there is a second line `\r\n`
3. The second line begins with any string `(\w*)` (in my example, `medidad`)
4. And, finally, there is a tab and the string `NCFS000` which match my condition.

Any tip will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To match something but not capture it, use a lookahead:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `dicha   NCFS000 dicha-n dicha   NCFS000 dicha   F   S(?=\R.+?NCFS000)`
- Replace with: `dicha   VMP00SF decir-v dicha   VMP00SF decir   F   S`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after, but not capturing:
    \R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n ...)
    .+?             # 1 or more any character but linebreak
    NCFS000         # literally
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]